# Using Jenkins to run Python script but having issue importing modules on the script

Tags: python, jenkins, python-requests, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am really new to Jenkins and Python so when I have initially researched for this problem, there has been a limit to my understanding. I am looking to write a Python script and for it to be run on Jenkins as part of some automated testing I wish to do. My script interacts with an API and hence imports the 'requests' module on Python. It works fine using the Python interpreter on my local machine but I have had issues when I have tried using the Jenkins Python script builder and so I am looking for a way around this.

As I mentioned, I have looked around the internet for solutions but as my knowledge on this topic is limited I have found it difficult to understand certain ideas that have been mentioned on the web. One lead I have had is related to the use of virtual environments on Jenkins, but as its something I've never used, I have struggled implementing it. I have installed the ShiningPanda Plugin on Jenkins, but I am unsure how to use it.

Any help given is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: What is the error that you see? How do you run the script in your pipeline? Are you running the script on a Windows or a Linux slave?

Comment: @DibakarAditya The error is 'No module named requests' which indicates that it has difficulty in terms of importing modules. The script is run in the Build section of the Jenkins job and uses a Python plugin in to execute Python scripts. Script is run on a Windows slave

Comment: Thanks for the info. Looks like the Python installation that the Python Plugin uses is not the same as that configured in the `PATH` environment variable of the user in your machine. Or Jenkins is running as a different user. You can verify this by running `import sys for p in sys.path:
    print(p)` (with the correct indentation).